# Understanding OSPF

Tags: routing, ospf

In OSPF, what happens first, the SPF tree or the SPF algorithm? Once the LSDB is created does the SPF tree get created first and then the SPF algorithm runs or does the SPF algorithm run and the SPF tree gets created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The algorithm builds and updates the tree - see [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) for details.